# jQuery load() and SEO - hard link to navigation

Tags: jquery, seo, load

Imagine a completely static website that uses jQuery .load() to include the site's main navigation on every page:

page1.html,
page2.html,
page3.html,...
page100.html,
nav.html (site navigation html)

Using jQuery to load the main navigation may be good for manageability (only have to edit the one included file "nav.html", less repeated code) but bad for SEO (crawlers cannot see the navigation on page1.html, page2.html etc and so cannot crawl the site).

Here's my question: If on every page there was a hard coded link to "nav.html", 
would that help the crawlers find the site navigation and get around the SEO problem? Assume we cannot use php or any other server side option to include html. Do crawlers need to link directly to another page and not a transitional page (in this case nav.html)? Would the crawlers get lost??

cheers.

P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View progressive enhancement as user1394965 suggested, OR, view this awesome article teaching us to use pushstate or history.js to use ajax content while crawlable by google :D

http://html5.gingerhost.com/

I have nothing to do with that site, just have it bookmarked because found it extremately easy to understand.

Comment: now this looks good. Definitely going to look into this some more. Thanks guys!